# Multiple Custom Expression with conditions for single bar chart

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I have been trying to calculate "Overtime" in a single chart for an analysis. The data table looks like this:

**Name  _Hours  _Shift Type**
Tom___5.5 ____   Long
Dick    ___6 _____  Long
Harry__7.7  _____Short
Jon ___4.5  _____Short
Tom ___5.6  _____Long
Dick    ___5.41 _____Long
Harry   ___5.22 _____Short
Jon ___5.03 _____Short
Tom ___4.84 _____Long
Dick    ___4.65 _____Long
Harry   ___4.46 _____Short
Jon ___4.27 _____Short
Tom ___4.08 _____Long
Dick    ___3.89 _____Long
Harry   ___3.7  _____Short
Jon ___3.51 _____Short

For Long shifts `sum([Hours])> 19` per employee is overtime.
For Short shifts `sum([Hours])> 18` per employee is overtime.

I have tried data limiting using:

`[Shift] = "Long" and Sum([Hours])>19` for long shift people
and `[Shift] = "Short" and Sum([Hours])>18` for short shift people.

and created two different charts and I was successful.

How do I do that in the same bar chart with two different calculations?
Any help would be nice.